# How to change ints in file in java?

Tags: java, file, int, export

I am making a simple game in java as my first project but I ran into a problem.

In class Undead_Menu, I have been trying to make it so that every time the user chooses the action number one in the while(menuRun) loop,the ints food and water will go will go down by one and overwrite what is in the text file Undead_save.txt .

Here is the code for class Undead_Menu:

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.lang.Object;
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class Undead_Menu
{
public static void main () throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
{

  //System code
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Undead_save.txt"));
  Random rand = new Random();
  Undead_Menu a=new Undead_Menu();
  Undead_Combat b=new Undead_Combat();
  boolean menuRun = true;
  int food =sc.nextInt();
  int water =sc.nextInt();

  while(menuRun)
  {
  if(food > 0 && water > 0)
  {
  System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
  System.out.println("# You see many Undead ahead...Limited supply...#");
  System.out.println("\t# You have " + food + " food.#");
  System.out.println("\t# You have " + water + " water.#");
  System.out.println("\n\tAction?");
  System.out.println("\n\t1.Fight one");
  System.out.println("\n\t2.Hide");

   String input = in.nextLine();
   if (input.equals("1"))
   {
    PrintWriter pwInput = new PrintWriter("Undead_save.txt");
    pwInput.println(food--);
    pwInput.println(water--); 
    b.combat();
   }

   if (input.equals("2"))
   {
     System.out.println("You hide,hoping they all pass by...");
     System.exit(0);
   }
}
   else
   {
System.out.println("You ran out of supplies...you will soon die...");
System.exit(0);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Undead_save.txt contains

```
    3
    4
```

and I want the file to contain

```
    2
    3
```

before so that the next time the main method is called,it will import ints food and water as 2 and 3.

Here is the code for the class Undead_Combat by the way:

```
        import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Undead_Combat
{ public void combat () throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
{
    //System objects
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 Random rand = new Random();
 Undead_Menu a=new Undead_Menu();

 //Game variables
 String[] enemies = { "Skeleton","Zombie","Vampire", "Ghost"};
 int maxEnemyHealth = 100;
 int enemyAttackDamage = 25;

 //Player Variables
 int health = 100;
 int attackDamage = 50;
 int numHealthPotions = 3;
 int healthPotionHealAmount = 50;
 int healthPotionDropChance = 50; //Percentage

 boolean running = true;

 System.out.println("The dead have risen...");

 GAME:
 while(running)
 {
  System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

  int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth);
  String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];
  System.out.println("\t# " + enemy + " has appeared... #\n");

  while(enemyHealth > 0)
  {
  System.out.println("\tYour hp: " + health);
  System.out.println("\t" + enemy + "'s hp: " + enemyHealth);
  System.out.println("\tYou have " + numHealthPotions + " potions");
  System.out.println("\n\tWhat is your command?");
  System.out.println("\t1. Attack");
  System.out.println("\t2. Use Potion");
  System.out.println("\t3. Run");

  String input = in.nextLine();
   if (input.equals("1"))
   {
   int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
   int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDamage);

   enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
   health -= damageTaken;

   System.out.println("\t You strike the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage!");
   System.out.println("\t The " + enemy + " hit you for " + damageTaken + " damage...");

   if (health < 1)
   {
   System.out.println("\tYou succumb to your injuries...");
   break;
   }

   }
   else if(input.equals("2"))
   {
    if (numHealthPotions > 0)
    {
    health += healthPotionHealAmount;
    numHealthPotions--;
    System.out.println("\tThe potion restored " + healthPotionHealAmount + " hp, " + "\n\tYou now have " + numHealthPotions + " left.");
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("\tYou have no potions to use left...");
    }
    }


   else if(input.equals("3"))
   {
    System.out.println("\tYou have ran...");
    a.main();
   }
   else
   {
   System.out.println("\tInvalid command...");
   }

 }

  if(health < 1)
  {
  System.out.println("\tYour corpse joins the assault...");
  break;
  }
  System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
  System.out.println("You killed one " + enemy );
  if(rand.nextInt(100) < healthPotionDropChance)
  {
  numHealthPotions++;
   System.out.println("\tThe " + enemy + " droped a potion!");
  }

  System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
  System.out.println("Whats is your next course of action?");
  System.out.println("1. Face one more.");
  System.out.println("2. hide.");

  String input = in.nextLine();

  while(!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2"))
  {
   System.out.println("Invalid Command...");
   input = in.nextLine();
  }

 if (input.equals("1"))
 {
 System.out.println("You look for next target...");
 continue GAME;
 }

 if (input.equals("2"))
 {
 System.out.println("You decide to hide until less of them are present...");
 a.main();
 }
 System.out.println("Will you fight again?");
 }
}
}
```

Comment: I can see what you want to happen, but what is the current behaviour? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) [Noctifer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4858412/noctifer).

While using **PrintWriter** class, you need to ensure that you **flush** and **close** it so that it releases all its resources, as it is not automatically flushed. In your code right now, since it is not closed so the changes are not being saved. The file is simply truncated.

If you don't want to flush and close it, you can use another method as:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileWriter,true);
```

The **true** passed to the constructor will cause the output to be flushed to the file after each call to **println** method.

Also, the decrement operator you are using is **post decrement** i.e, **food--** and **water--**. So the changes will not reflect in the file at the moment. It will first write to the file, and then decrements.
So change it to pre decrement operator.

Here's what you need to change in the **Undead_Menu** class

```
 PrintWriter pwInput = new PrintWriter("Undead_save.txt");
 pwInput.println(--food);   //change food-- to --food
 pwInput.println(--water);  //change water-- to --water
 pwInput.flush();           //flushing the PrintWriter
 pwInput.close();           //closing the PrintWriter
 b.combat();
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I had no idea you had to flush or close a PrintWriter.